# How to choose between GeForce GTX 1080 graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-cards

I am going to buy a HTC Vive VR headset and a new PC dedicated to running it - which I am currently trying to spec.

I am confused about the price disparity between graphics cards with the **same chipset**. For example, several manufacturers produce a card using the NVidia GeForce GTX 1080 chipset & the disparity in price is significant. Currently, the most expensive cards cost 60% more than the least expensive one.

https://www.mwave.com.au/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-1080

For reference, selected prices (in Australian dollars) from the above website in Mar/2017 are:

```
Galax GeForce GTX 1080 EXOC 8GB                  $749
ASUS  GeForce GTX 1080 ROG Strix Gaming OC 8GB   $1199
MSI   GeForce GTX 1080 Sea Hawk EK X 8GB         $1199
EVGA  GeForce GTX 1080 FTW HYBRID GAMING 8GB     $1199
EVGA  GeForce GTX 1080 FTW2 Gaming iCX 8GB       $1199
```

Some manufacturers even produce different models using the same chipset. I naively expected that cards using the same chipset would give roughly the same performance. Given the price disparity, I suspect this is not the case or there must be some other significant points of differentiation (aka features). I'd like to understand a bit better what these are.

Just so I don't get in trouble for being off-topic, here's my current dilemma: in what ways is a Galax GeForce GTX 1080 EXOC 8GB better/worse than an MSI GeForce GTX **1070** Gaming X 8GB? (Apart from the former costing only 17% more ($110) than the latter.) However, as mentioned above, I really would also like to understand how the higher price tags on some graphics cards are justified.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could just wait and get a GTX 1080 ti Founder Edition, which is on par with the Titan X, has 11GB ram, only costs $699.

Comment: $US699 == $A1129, so 51% more than the Galax EXOC.

Comment: Oh, yeah.....right *facedesk*   Seriously, we need a global standard........I say Bitcoin....or just go back to gold.

Comment: @NZKshatriya [There are now \[n+1\] competing currencies XD](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: @ArtOfCode huh? this question has nothing to do with tech support? how is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll be reviewing the reasons for price-differences on graphics cards with the exact same GPU chip, then I'll give a recommendation between the Galax GTX1080 and the MSI GTX1070.

There are indeed quite a few properties that can set apart different graphics cards and which can influence the price:

- **Clocking.** This is the most obvious one. The OEM can adapt the base and the maximal clock of the GPU and give it more performance this way, just like a higher-clocked CPU would be faster. Normally more is charged for higher clocked GPUs and they can offer a couple of percents of perfomance boost as well.
- **Cooling and OC.** OEMs can customize the cooling for the chips and as such charge more for better cooling. They can also allow you to overclock their GPUs which usually requires good cooling. Better cooling means the GPU can maintain it's turbo-clock longer and it means you may be able to increase the base clock as well by using OC utilities, this increases performance and thus price.
- **Noise.** GPUs are notoriously loud and as such OEMs can try and minimize this noise. This may include using slower-spinning and / or more efficient fans which tend to be more costly. Additionally the OEM may add in custom board logic that turns the fans off if the load / GPU temperature is low enough, which drastically reduces noise. Of course, less noise is harder to achieve and thus more expensive.
- **Optical Design.** You may have noticed this trend, but everything on a computer has to have lights these days. This requires LEDs and the accompying circuit logic which costs money and also the placement costs designer time. So if you want a fancier graphics card, this will obviously cost you more.
- **Brand Reputation.** Some brands may have a higher reputation and / or better warranty conditions (eg EVGA). People may really want to buy their stuff and thus they can demand higher prices, whereas a company without such a reputation may has to offer lower prices to still get sales off.

---

Now for the demanded comparison. The Galax (aka KFA2) GTX1080 EXOC ([1](http://ufdisciple.com/2016/09/galax-gtx-1080-exoc-review/) [2 (German)](http://game2gether.de/hardware/kfa2-geforce-gtx-1080-exoc-test-review/)) has far less reviews and not a single from a high-reputation source (at least that I could identify), whereas the MSI GTX1070 Gaming X ([1](https://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/MSI/GTX_1070_Gaming_X/) [2](https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/msi-geforce-gtx-1070-gaming-x-review,1.html) [3](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-graphics-card-roundup,4751-5.html)) has more reviews from more well-reputated magazines.

The GTX1070 will perform worse than the GTX1080 (mainly because the 1080 got *more cores* at a similar clock) and I expect the GTX1080 to deliver 20-40% more FPS than the 1070 (which is by itself ~5% faster than a stock 1070).

It's your decision, I expect both cards to have a similar price / perfomance point with the 1080 being off slightly worse, but of course $100 can also be invested elsewhere (for example if your CPU is pretty old).

Comment: And then there is the new kid on the block, the GTX 1080 ti FE.  11GB GDDR5X, outperforms the Titan X, costs half as much....